# send/channelise HTTP response back to browser

Tags: java, http, sockets, browser, proxy

I have made a localhost HTTP proxy in Java listening on port 3000. I am able to channelise the HTTP requests to the proxy(browser sends them using a random high valued port ~50000) and obtain the HTTP responses. Problem is that I don't know how to channelise these responses back to the browser so as to display them.

In another way, how can I obtain the port on which the browser listens so that I will set up a socket to send the data on that port. Is it so that I have to send the data to the same high valued port from which I received it? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: You dont have to. Send the response on the socket where you've read the request.

Comment: Do I have to send to ~50000(random port used by browser) or to 3000 where I set the proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser doesn't listen on some port for any incoming HTTP traffic. The browser is the client and initiates connections, doesn't listen for / receive any. In your proxy, you should listen for incoming browser requests, hold on to their sockets, forward the requests to where they're supposed to go, wait for the responses, and finally send the responses back to the waiting browsers, through the sockets you have held open.

Comment: Do you mean I have to send data back to THE same high valued port ~ 50000 from where I got the request and not 3000 where the proxy is set up?

Comment: You have to send data back to the same socket from where you received the request. Do not create a new socket ! Sockets are two-way communication pipes.

Comment: As Nicolas says above, sockets are for two-way communication, so you can not only use them to get data from the browser, but also send data back to it. In fact, the browser expects data back from that same connection!